# output data collected in a loop to a file each time it loops - Python

Tags: python

```
def lossFile(eD):
    output = open('lossreport.txt', 'w')
    for i in eD:
        output.write(i + ' ')
    viewReport = input('Would you like to view the data stored in the report? Enter (y/n): \n')
    if viewReport == 'yes' or viewReport =='y':
        outprint = True
        return outprint
    else:
        output.close()
        print('Your data has been successfully been written to the file.')
def readfile(rF):
    if rF:
        file = open('lossreport.txt','r')
        readList = file.readlines()
        file.close()
        for i in readList:
            print(i)
```

I am writing a program that outputs some basic information to a file. It does this with no problems, it collects a List that stores the username how much they marked down and the date and time it was done.

The problem is the program has a loop that allows the user to work with a new invoice if they please - but when the user enters the loop again to enter these values the data stored in the file is over written.
I am trying to get it to show the data for each invoice they choose to work with.

Here is a sample of the file output:

```
'User: GS Amount Off:(in dollars) 25.00 Date & Time: Wed Jun  2 20:13:13 2021'
```

Comment: `open('lossreport.txt', 'w')` effectively means "erase this file and let them write to it". To append, use `open('lossreport.txt', 'a')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `open(lossreport.txt,'w')` This will overwrite the file.

You need to append it by using - `open(lossreport.txt,'a')`

Check this out -
[File modes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-handling-python/)